# How can I retrieve all records (more than 5000 and/or more than 1 page) with the Dynamics 365 Web API in a Dynamics CRM organization with a C# plugin?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I need to count all of the **Task** records with a **regardingobjectid** of a specific **Account** and a **statecode** of **0**. This needs to be done with the new 365 Web API and REST that came with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016. Here is how the basic query (without paging) is done with Javascript:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/tasks?$filter=_regardingobjectid_value eq 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 and  statecode eq 0", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\",odata.maxpagesize=5000");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                var activityid = results.value[i]["activityid"];
            }
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

Furthermore, this must be done in a fashion that allows it to retrieve more than 5000 records. Information on how to do this can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx

Here is how I could query up to 5000 records with a C# plugin and FETCH XML:

```
int count = 0;
            string fetchTemplate =
                @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml - platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                    <entity name='activitypointer'>
                        <attribute name='activitytypecode' />
                        <attribute name='subject' />
                        <attribute name='prioritycode' />
                        <attribute name='regardingobjectid' />
                        <attribute name='statecode' />
                        <attribute name='instancetypecode' />
                        <attribute name='community' />
                        <attribute name='scheduledend' />
                        <attribute name='activityid' />
                        <filter type='and'>
                            <condition attribute='isregularactivity' operator='eq' value='1' />
                            <condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' />
                        </filter>    
                        <link-entity name='account' from='accountid' to='regardingobjectid' alias='ab'>
                            <filter type='and'>
                                <condition attribute='accountid' operator='eq' uitype='account' value='{0}' />
                            </filter>
                        </link-entity>
                    </entity>
                </fetch>";
            fetchTemplate = String.Format(fetchTemplate, entityId.ToString());
            List<Entity> records = context.RetrieveAll(fetchTemplate);
            if (records != null && records.Count > 0)
            {
                count = records.Count;
            }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2016, Visual Studio Professional 2015, relevant Nuget packages, and the Plugin Registration Tool.

I have come to StackOverflow for help with this because I cannot find a simple example of a REST query online for Microsoft Dynamics CRM that can retrieve more than 5000 records in a C# plugin.

I am particularly interested in the @odata.nextlink property and how this enables the restful retrieval of multiple pages (and potentially more than 5000 records).

If you would like to help me enhance my current C# plugin code so that it can retrieve more than 5000 records, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: From the link you posted: `a maximum of 5000 entities will be returned for each request. If there are more entities that match the query filter criteria, a @odata.nextLink property will be returned with the results. Use the value of the @odata.nextLink property with a new GET request to return the next page of data.` My C# is rather weak, but @odata.nextLink should be returning a value that you can use to call the API again for the next 5000 records.

Comment: Secondly, would this be easier to get through a report in CRM? See this link: http://www.powerobjects.com/2015/11/09/determining-total-record-counts/

Comment: Thank you for your time and comments. Now, if only I could make a simple query with C# and REST... I'll be working on it more tomorrow.

Comment: Unfortunately using reports won't do any good. After obtaining the count, I need to update a custom field in another record with that count. Honestly, I think that could still be done with rollup or calculated fields. However, I am doing this with REST in order to become proficient with it and plugin development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to retrieve all the records to perform a count. FetchXML includes aggregations that allow us to calculate max, min, average and [COUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/gg309565.aspx#Count). The following is an example to count all the accounts in the system:

```
<fetch version="1.0" mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="accountid" aggregate="count" alias="count" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

The WebAPI have a [$count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx#bkmk_retrieveCount) query option, but unfortunately, it's also limited by the same restriction so it's not helpful in this case:

> The count value does not represent the total number of entities in the
>   system. It is limited by the maximum number of entities that can be
>   returned.

So, after all this introduction, how we calculate the number of records using the WebAPI and avoiding the 5000 records restriction then? Passing our FetchXML as a query in the GET to the WebAPI, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt607533.aspx#bkmk_useFetchXML) is how to use it. After encoding the previous FetchXML example, we ended up with the following request:

```
GET/api/data/v8.2/accounts?fetchXml=%3Cfetch+version%3D%221.0%22+mapping%3D%22logical%22+aggregate%3D%22true%22%3E%3Centity+name%3D%22account%22%3E%3Cattribute+name%3D%22accountid%22+aggregate%3D%22count%22+alias%3D%22count%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fentity%3E%3C%2Ffetch%3E+
```

And this is the response with our count:
[image]

If you still want to retrieve all the records, [here](http://www.inogic.com/blog/2015/12/execute-fetchxml-using-web-api-in-dynamics-crm-2016/) you can find an example of how to use the paging cookie with the WebAPI.

Comment: When you say, "Passing our FetchXML as a query in the GET to the WebAPI, this is how to use it." I am still confused. The page that you link to has no C# code in it. Can you provide example C# code using: GET/api/data/v8.2/accounts?fetchXml=%3Cfetch+version%3D%221.0%22+mapping%3D%22logical%22+aggregate%3D%22true%22%3E%3Centity+name%3D%22account%22%3E%3Cattribute+name%3D%22accountid%22+aggregate%3D%22count%22+alias%3D%22count%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fentity%3E%3C%2Ffetch%3E+

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt779074.aspx) you can see an example of how to use the WebAPI from C# (there's some code to handle the authentication also). Let me say that if you want to execute this from a plugin, you should use the Organization Service provided in the plugin context (still using the WCF endpoint) instead of consuming the WebAPI endpoint like that.